# how to update only one handle in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, handles

I have a gui with few handles I created , not the one who come with the gui when you create him like handles.axes handles.popupmenu etc,and I have a code running when a button is clicked and after the code is finished I want to update only 1 handle [lets call him handle.one] but not all the rest so when the callback function is over the other handles will get back to their original value.
I know guidata is updating handles but it updates all my handles .

edit:

```
if (get(handles.checkbox11,'Value'))
    avg=0;
    tmp=[get(handles.checkbox11,'Value'),get(handles.checkbox12,'Value'),get(handles.checkbox13,'Value'),get(handles.checkbox14,'Value'),get(handles.checkbox15,'Value')];
    for i=1:5
        avg=tmp(i)+avg;
        if(tmp(i)~=0)
            switch i

                case 1
                    handles.band_three=handles.band_three+handles.Ys13;
                case 2
                    handles.band_three=handles.band_three+handles.Ys23;
                case 3
                    handles.band_three=handles.band_three+handles.Ys33;
                case 4
                    handles.band_three=handles.band_three+handles.Ys43;
                case 5
                    handles.band_three=handles.band_three+handles.Ys53;
            end
        end
    end
    handles.band_three=handles.band_three/avg;
    handles.final=handles.band_three;
    axes(handles.axes8);
    plot(abs(handles.band_three))
end
```

after this callback finish to run handles.band_three and handles.final goes back to 0.
if i write down at the end guidata(hObject, handles); then handles.final and handles.band_three will be saved.
I want to save only handles.final but handles.band_three to go back to 0.

Comment: I don't follow. Please provide a concise example that reproduces your issue. See [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why not set `handles.band_three` to 0 and then update using `guidata`?